# Do comments have reputations or not?

Tags: bug, comments, reputation

For my previous question

[What is difference between a comment and an Answer?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1941/what-is-difference-between-a-comment-and-an-answer)

[ben](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7627/ben-brocka) gave this as answer from [comment privileges page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

> What are comments?
>
> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, **but do not generate reputation**. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.
>
> Please note that you can always comment on your own posts, and any part of your questions. However, commenting on other people's posts is a privilege.

but what i have realized is for in this [answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/81698/are-animated-images-considered-bad-ux/81729#81729) when someone up-voted one of my comment i got 6 reputations added to my account.

Do comments have reputations or that reputation is for some other purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, comments doesn't have reputation. The answer given before is the correct answer. The only thing you “earn” from reputation is three badges:

- [Tumbleweed](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/badges/21/tumbleweed) - Asked a question with zero score, no answers, **no comments**, and low views for a week.
- [Commentator](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/commentator) - Leave **10 comments**.
- [Pundit](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/badges/24/pundit) - Leave **10 comments** with **score of 5** or more.

In your case, you didn’t get 6 reputation points from the comment. You got 10 reps for one up vote, and -4 reps for two down votes.

[image]

You can read more of how reputation works in the article [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 1):

Comments don't give you reputation, no. All of your reputation points [are accounted for from your standard posts](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/68392/bharath?tab=reputation) and you can keep track of reputation changes from your profile Reputation tab.