# Should comments have reputation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I understand that currently comments do not provide reputation. 
That is covered in this question: [Do comments have reputations or not?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1960/do-comments-have-reputations-or-not/1961#1961)

My question is: Should they?

I have found many comments made in various posts to be very useful and contribute positively to the community:

- Guiding new users to use the proper format or modify their question to fit the UXSE guidelines
- Requesting (and providing) additional details and context often necessary for our domain
- Giving some very beneficial information regarding the question, but it doesn't answer the question in its entirety

It would be great if we could promote and reward this positive behavior.

Unfortunately, there are some caveats that may be hard to deal with. Two that come to mind are:

- Comments that are answers and should be submitted as answers.
- Comments that are funny and clever receiving lots of upvotes but not contributing to the question or the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No. The point of giving reputation to questions / answers is to encourage people to submit them. We don't really want people to leave comments beyond  when really necessary (requesting clarification on the post, primarily).

The purpose of Stack Exchange is a repository for problems and their solutions. Comments just add noise and distraction to that purpose.